# Como guardo questoes em um array de apontadores

Tags: c, string, arquivo

Boa noite

Venho aqui tentar dissipar um problema de programação que me ocorre. Nesta solução, eu tenho um ficheiro com várias questões, sendo que cada questão pode ser uma questão de um dos 3 temas seguintes:

1. GEO - Geografia
2. MAT - Matemática
3. HIS - História

Se o utilizador na execução do programa escolher, responder a questões de geografia, então vai ser invocado um metodo que selecciona apenas as questões de geografia. Esse metodo possui entre outro código o seguinte:

```
while (fgets(pergunta, 150, f) != NULL) // ler ficheiro linha a linha
    {
        sscanf(pergunta,"%ld", &elapsed_seconds); // ler cada poergunta do ficheiro
        length = sizeof(pergunta) - 4; // pegar no tamanho dos primeiros 4 caracteres

        for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
        {
            if (pergunta[j] == 'G' && pergunta[j + 1] == 'E' && pergunta[j + 2] == 'O') // se a pergunta é de GEO
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <= sizeof(questoes); i++)
                {

                    //Problema 
                    if(!questoes[i]) // se encontrar posicao vazia
                        questoes[i] = pergunta; // guarda pergunta no apontador

                    if (i == sizeof(questoes))
                    {
                        resultadoRetomado = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (pergunta[j] != 'G' && pergunta[j + 1] != 'E' && pergunta[j + 2] != 'O')
            {
                pergunta[j] = '\0';
            }
        }

        }
```

Problema:Se for encontrada uma pergunta de geografia, o apontador `char* questoes[50]`, passado como parametro para o método, vai ser percorrido e a primeira pergunta encontrada será armazenada. Eu pretendo e tentei alterar este algoritmo por forma a verificar se existe alguma posicao vazia no conjunto de apontadores.

Objetivo: Pretendo guardar no apontador char* questoes[50] um conjunto de 50 questões. Como posso alterar este código por forma a percorrer o ficheiro e guardar as 50 questões?

Desde já Obrigado,